# How to show that if $u$ is a partial isometry then $u = u u^\ast u$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H, H'$ be Hilbert spaces, $u \in B(H,H')$ and $u^\ast $ its adjoint.

I am trying to show that if $u$ is a partial isometry then $u = uu^\ast u$. My idea was to write $H = \ker u \oplus (\ker u)^\bot = \ker u \oplus \overline{\mathrm{im}(u^\ast)}$, $h = x \oplus y$.

Then I tried to use this to prove that $\|uh - uu^\ast u h\|^2$ equals $0$ but all I could show was that

$$ \|uh - uu^\ast u h\|^2 = \|uy\|^2 -  \|u^\ast uy\|^2$$

and I can't proceed from here.

> How to show what I'm trying to show?

Comment: See http://www.math.tamu.edu/~pskoufra/OANotes-PartialIsometries.pdf

Comment: @JankoBracic Thank you for the link, it helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\xi\in H$, and $\eta\in ker(u)$. Then
$$\langle u^*uu^*\xi,\eta\rangle=\langle uu^*\xi,u\eta\rangle=0=\langle \xi,u\eta\rangle=\langle u^*\xi,\eta\rangle$$

Since $u$ is a partial isometry, then $u$ preserves inner product on $\ker(u)^\perp=\overline{Image(u^*)}$, so for $\eta\in\ker(u)^\perp$ we have
$$\langle u^*uu^*\xi,\eta\rangle=\langle u(u^*\xi),u\eta\rangle=\langle u^*\xi,\eta\rangle$$

Now using the fact that $H=ker(u)\oplus ker(u)^\perp$, we conclude that $u^*uu^*=u^*$, which gives
$$uu^*u=(u^*uu^*)^*=(u^*)^*=u$$